# Problem with stretching, making a responsive web page + boxes

Tags: html, css

The website that I'm making has an image that I am using as the main logo, and I'm trying to adjust the website for phones, computers, and anything else that can be used. The code does work but it stretches the image wider or taller depending on the screen.

I feel like there must be a way around this.

Another question relative to this is how would I make a box on top of the CSS background I already have. I tried using margins and borders but I can't seem to figure out how to fill them in (hopefully I can link it right)

```
<meta name="viewport"content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

```
    <img src="/logo.png"
    width="400" 
    height="125"
    style="width:100%;"
    style="hight:auto;"/>
```

Comment: Please read the description for the tags more carefully. `web` specifically states to not be used at all. `layout` states that it should not be used for questions related to CSS. Then only ask one question per question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take at [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

In particular, `object-fit: cover;` might be what you need. It will maintain the aspect ratio of the image and make sure it always covers the content box. The tradeoff is that parts of the image may be cropped and the image will get scaled to achieve this.